# SQL Server: Create Trigger For Audit / History Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am creating my first SQL Server Trigger, and looking to INSERT into a "History" table after insert into another table. I think I have most of the code written, but can't seem to get the syntax finished. The current format states that the "HistoryColumnName" and "HistoryNewValue" are invalid. I have tried a JOIN to the variable table @HistoryRecord but it doesnt really make sense as they are independent.

Code below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CreateHardwareAssetHistoryRecord
ON HardwareAsset
AFTER INSERT AS

DECLARE
@HardwareAssetID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@HardwareAssetTitle VARCHAR(256),
@HardwareAssetSerialNumber VARCHAR(256)
SET @HardwareAssetID = (SELECT HardwareAssetID FROM inserted)
SET @HardwareAssetTitle = (SELECT HardwareAssetTitle FROM inserted)
SET @HardwareAssetSerialNumber = (SELECT HardwareAssetSerialNumber FROM inserted)

DECLARE @HistoryRecord TABLE (HistoryColumnName VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, HistoryNewValue VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)
INSERT @HistoryRecord(HistoryColumnName,HistoryNewValue) VALUES('Asset Name', @HardwareAssetTitle)
INSERT @HistoryRecord(HistoryColumnName,HistoryNewValue) VALUES('Serial Number', @HardwareAssetSerialNumber)

BEGIN

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT HistoryColumnName,HistoryNewValue FROM @HistoryRecord)

INSERT INTO HardwareAssetHistory
(HardwareAssetHistoryChangeTypeID, HardwareAssetHistoryUpdatedByID, HardwareAssetHistoryColumnName, HardwareAssetHistoryOldValue, HardwareAssetHistoryNewValue, HardwareAssetHistoryHardwareAssetID)
SELECT '1', HardwareAssetCreatedByID, HistoryColumnName, '', HistoryNewValue, HardwareAssetID
FROM HardwareAsset
WHERE HardwareAssetID = @HardwareAssetID

END
GO
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use a temporal table instead. https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjKt5OGg8PSAhUJzbwKHQf5B_8QFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdn935015.aspx&usg=AFQjCNG2VZa8v6Y_rCW-rWB_2VTUW1-Idw&sig2=fouMv9WhcDjahToxkDiWoQ&bvm=bv.148747831,d.dGc&cad=rja If you are just starting to learn SQL let me assure you that triggers are to be avoided. Although you can learn important concepts in building one, in practice they are usually not a good idea

Comment: The first thing to learn is a mistake made by _every_ first time trigger writer. That is that a trigger is called once per batch, not once per row. In other words the table `inserted` can have more than one row, which means the statement `SET @HardwareAssetID = (SELECT HardwareAssetID FROM inserted)` will throw an error in this case

Comment: Does the table `HardwareAsset` have a column called `HistoryColumnName`? I guess not. That is the immediate cause of your error, but it's just a symptom of a bigger problem that there are some other concepts you need to understand

Comment: Can I also recommend looking at existing audit trail code generation: https://autoaudit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without your temp table and referring back original `HardwareAsset` table by picking another value:

NOTE: as pointed by @nick.mcdermaid, below will not work when there are multiple rows as we are using variables.

<strike>CREATE TRIGGER CreateHardwareAssetHistoryRecord
        ON HardwareAsset
    AFTER INSERT AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @HardwareAssetID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @HardwareAssetTitle VARCHAR(256),
            @HardwareAssetSerialNumber VARCHAR(256),
            @HardwareAssetCreatedByID INT --CHANGE TO WHAT IS DATA TYPE OF THIS</strike>

```
    SELECT @HardwareAssetID = HardwareAssetID, @HardwareAssetTitle = HardwareAssetTitle
           , @HardwareAssetSerialNumber = HardwareAssetSerialNumber
           , @HardwareAssetCreatedByID = HardwareAssetCreatedByID FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO HardwareAssetHistory(HardwareAssetHistoryChangeTypeID
                       , HardwareAssetHistoryUpdatedByID, HardwareAssetHistoryColumnName
                       , HardwareAssetHistoryOldValue, HardwareAssetHistoryNewValue
                      , HardwareAssetHistoryHardwareAssetID)
    VALUES ('1', @HardwareAssetCreatedByID, 'Asset Name', '',  @HardwareAssetTitle
                                                     , @HardwareAssetID),
        ('1', @HardwareAssetCreatedByID, 'Serial Number', '',  @HardwareAssetSerialNumber
                                                    , @HardwareAssetID)
END
GO
```

UPDATE: This will work with multiple rows as well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CreateHardwareAssetHistoryRecord
    ON HardwareAsset
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @insertedTemp AS TABLE (HardwareAssetID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, HardwareAssetTitle VARCHAR(256), HardwareAssetSerialNumber VARCHAR(256), HardwareAssetCreatedByID INT)

    INSERT INTO @insertedTemp(HardwareAssetID, HardwareAssetTitle, HardwareAssetSerialNumber, HardwareAssetCreatedByID) 
    SELECT HardwareAssetID, HardwareAssetTitle, HardwareAssetSerialNumber, HardwareAssetCreatedByID FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO HardwareAssetHistory(HardwareAssetHistoryChangeTypeID
                       , HardwareAssetHistoryUpdatedByID, HardwareAssetHistoryColumnName
                       , HardwareAssetHistoryOldValue, HardwareAssetHistoryNewValue
                      , HardwareAssetHistoryHardwareAssetID)    
    SELECT '1', HardwareAssetCreatedByID, 'Asset Name', '',  HardwareAssetTitle, @HardwareAssetID
    FROM    @insertedTemp

UNION    

    SELECT '1', HardwareAssetCreatedByID, 'Serial Number', '',  HardwareAssetSerialNumber, HardwareAssetID
    FROM    @insertedTemp    
END
GO
```

Comment: This will not function as expected when `inserted` has more than one record. It will function if you dispense with all of the variables and simply do an insert/select

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid good point mate, new solution works with multiple rows.

Comment: I don't know if `@insertedTemp` is even necessary here but I don't quite understand the logic

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes you can take values directly from `inserted` and insert them for all the columns. The logic should be clear, get the inserted rows and insert values of `Asset name` and `Serial Number` columns into audit table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid & TheVillageIdiot really appreciate all your help, this has been a good learning experience and help me understand triggers better and maybe worth expanding my knowledge to look at alternatives to triggers.